# Multiple usb cameras on Raspberry Pi using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi

I would like to connect 2 usb webcams to a RaspberryPI and be able to get at least 1920 x 1080 frames at 10 fps using OpenCV.  Has anyone done this and knows if this is possible?  I am worried that the PI has only 1 usb bus?? (usb2) and might get a usb bandwidth problem.

Currently I am using an Odroid and it has a usb2 and usb3 bus so I can connect 1 camera to each without any problemo..

Answer (score -1):

What i have found in the past with this is no matter what you select using OpenCV for bandwidth options the cameras try to take up as much bandwidth as they want.

This has led to multiple cameras on a single USB port being a no-no.

That being said, this will depend on your camera and is very likely worth testing. I regularly use HD-3000 Microsoft cameras and they do not like working on the same port, even on my beefy i7 laptop. This is because the limitation is in the USB Host Bandwidth and not processing power etc.

I have had a similar development process to you inthe past though, and selected an Odroid XU4 because it had the multiple USB hosts for the cameras. It also means you have a metric tonne more processing power available and more importantly can buy and use the on-board chip if you want to create a custom electronics design.

Comment: yes i am using odroid xu4 as well but the support and availible code to run different hardware is horrible!